# Get Image from image View

Tags: objective-c, ios7

if we add more than one View to imageView and NSString also. Is it possible to get image from ImageView that contain all images and strings etc?
like this

[image]

Comment: Like what exactly? If not rendered into one, the image you posted have multiple subviews.

Comment: see the icon at bottom left and string at bottom right. and yes i want an image with multiple subviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand in your question, you have added an ImageView for the building, another for the video symbol (as a subview) and a UILabel (again as a subview) for the time. You want all these to be rendered as a single UIImage. For this, you can use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The screenshot UIImage will contain your desired image.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer suits you, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.